# What is the definition of a branch of a function in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 39 he defines the branch of the logarithm:

[image]

However in the exercise 17, page 44, he asks about the branch of the function $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$ :

[image]

So how can Conway ask something he didn't define? How can I solve this question?

Comment: Seems like a shortsight by Conway. Luckily, the principle branch has a common definition that is readily found in many other sources.

Comment: @ChantryCargill could you give me another source? thanks

Comment: Well, [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalValue.html) is a good definition. The canonical choice here would be the positive root. You could also look at the square root function as $e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can infer the definition:

If G is open connected set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function such that $z = 1 - f(x)^2$ (i.e. $f(x)^2 = 1-z$) then $f$ is a branch of the given function.

This is similar to how you take square root of a positive number. You have two solutions, one negative and one positive. These would correspond to two branches when talking about functions. Looking for continuous functions is the key. Thus if you pick the negative root, the function has to be negative in an open neighborhood (that's the negative branch).